# Which integer combinations of $n$-th roots of unity are zero?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-polynomials

> Let $\omega$ be primitive $n$-th root of unity. Can we determine all tuples of integers $(c_1, c_2,\ldots,c_n) $ such that $$c_1+c_2 \omega + c_3 \omega^2+\cdots+ c_n \omega^{n-1}=0 \,?$$

It is clear to me that if $ n$ is prime, then this means $ \omega$ is a root of polynomial $$c_1 + c_2x + c_3x^2+\cdots+c_nx^{n-1} =0 \,,$$ which implies $c_1 = c_2 = c_3\cdots = c_n $ as minimal polynomial of $\omega$ in this case is $${1+x+x^2+\dotsb+x^{n-1}}\,.$$ But if $ n$ is not prime and $\phi(n) $ divides $(n-1) $ then other solutions are also possible. Does this become highly dependent on $ n$? Or can we still say something for general $ n$?

Comment: Obviously, we're going to answer it. But what are your thoughts regarding the question.

Comment: Hint: This isn't as much about roots of unity as it is about vectors in the plane.

Comment: @Arthur is correct. Notice that $n^{th}$ roots of unity lie on vertices of $n$-sided regular polygon with one side along real axis.

Comment: Answer depends on $n$. Easy case is when $n$ is prime. Can you do that case, Aditya? By the way, perhaps you want to specify that $\omega$ is a *primitive* $n$th root of unity?

Comment: @Arthur Is it really? It’s basically asking for any linear relations within the $n$-th roots of unity and linear algebra alone doesn’t seem to get you far without knowing a thing or two about the roots first, does it?

Comment: @k.stm For any such problem, yes, you need to know which vectors you're working with. You can't get away from that fact. But talking about roots of unity is in my opinion a red herring, hinting too much at the complex numbers and the multiplicative property that defines the $\omega_n$'s. That will not help in this problem. Distilling it down to "The corners of a regular $n$-gon centered at the origin (with diameter $1$)" removes such distractions.

Comment: @Arthur Okay, well. I wouldn’t know how to proceed here without examining the roots of unity further, I’m excited about the solution then.

Comment: @Arthur in my opinion the way to go about this problem is via the algebra of cyclotomic fields rather than the geometry of regular polygons. How would you prove using geometry that if $n$ is prime then the only vanishing linear combinations of the corners of a regular $n$-gon are the ones with all coefficients equal? As a statement about vanishing sums of $n$th roots of unity, it admits a simple proof.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The $c_i$ are real, not rational. So $1$ and $\omega$ together span the plane, as long as $n\geq3$. Any power of $\omega$ is a linear combination of the two.

Comment: @Arthur, good point. I wonder whether Aditya meant to restrict attention to rational coefficients, as I think that makes for a more interesting problem.

Comment: There are many published papers on the topic of vanishing sums of roots of unity, e.g., Conway & Jones, Trigonometric diophantine equations, Acta. Arith. 30 (1976) 229-240; Gary Sivek, On vanishing sums of distinct roots of unity, Integers 10 (2010) 365-368 #A31 http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/k31/k31.pdf ; U Zannier, Vanishing sums of roots of unity, Rend. Sem. Mat. Univ. Pol. Torino 53 (1995) No. 4, 487-495, http://www.seminariomatematico.polito.it/rendiconti/cartaceo/53-4/487.pdf (continued)

Comment: (continued) Lam & Leung, On vanishing sums of roots of unity, Journal of Algebra 224 No. 1 (2000) 91-109, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869399980894 and the papers in the references of these papers, and probably others.

Comment: I don't see what @Arthur is aiming at? Surely this equation holds if and only if $c_0+c_1x+\cdots+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}$ is a multiple of $\Phi_n(x)$.

Comment: I apologize @Arthur. I missed the fact that the question was edited.

Comment: @Jyrki maybe not so easy to classify those $(c_0,c_1,\dots,c_{n-1})$ such that $c_0+c_1x+\cdots+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}$ is a multiple of $\Phi_n(x)$.

Comment: Previous (unanswered) question on this topic: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3572242/vanishing-sums-of-roots-of-unity Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851111/n-th-roots-of-unity-summing-to-0

Comment: Have you had a look at any of the links I've given in my comment and my answer, Aditya?

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Yes.

Comment: Good. I hope you found something useful in them.

Answer (score 3):

Many papers have been written on this question. I'd suggest having a look at

1. Conway & Jones, [Trigonometric diophantine equations](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa30/aa3033.pdf), Acta. Arith. 30 (1976) 229-240,
2. U Zannier, [Vanishing sums](http://www.seminariomatematico.polito.it/rendiconti/cartaceo/53-4/487.pdf) of roots of unity, Rend. Sem. Mat. Univ. Pol. Torino 53 (1995) No. 4, 487-495,
3. Lam & Leung, On [vanishing sums](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869399980894) of roots of unity, Journal of Algebra 224 No. 1 (2000) 91-109,
4. Gary Sivek, On [vanishing sums](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/k31/k31.pdf) of distinct roots of unity, Integers 10 (2010) 365-368 #A31.

Comment: This should be written in comments.

Comment: If you have a better answer, @SarGe I invite you to post it.

Comment: Henry B Mann , ON LINEAR RELATIONS BETWEEN ROOTS OF UNITY ,1965
This paper seems also related to the question.

Comment: @Alex, yes, it's probably in the references of the other papers so I figured anyone who followed the links I gave would come across the Mann paper. Do you have a link to it online?

Comment: [link](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/S0025579300005210 )